# Ordered Many-to-many

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

Is there an elegant way in symfony to modelize a many-to-many relation with an additionnal field **for a total order** ?
I understand why one needs to create an additionnal entity for relations attributes, but here this 'position' could be included in the classic ArrayCollection of classic many-to-many relation, with the position in the array corresponding to the position attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a Doctrine question then a Symfony question but the answer can be found [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#ordering-to-many-collections). In short, you have to add the `@OrderBy` mapping to the field, like so:

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bar")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $bar;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the position attribute is not in one of the entities, but in the relation (example User and Group, and i want that groups for a user to be ordered by preference of the user)

Comment: Well...you could create an extra `Position` entity that links the `User` and `Group` entities...

Comment: The point is how to not doing this, because the position attribute is special wrt other relation attributes, as the knoledge can be embeded in an array.